# How to draw a triangular prism in latex?

Tags: diagrams, 3d

How do draw a right triangular prism in latex in this point of view?
[image]

And moreover, how can I add the right angle label like this?
[image]

Finally, how to add lines in the same figure?
[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You could start with ti*k*Z (see [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc} % 3d is not really needed here but convenient for extensions

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0.5cm,0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0cm)},
z={(0cm,1cm)},font=\sffamily]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CornerScale}{1.5}
\draw (0,0,0) coordinate[label=below:A] (A) -- ++ (8,0,0)
coordinate[label=below:B] (B) -- ++ (0,5,0)
coordinate[label=below right:C] (C)  -- ++ (0,0,2)
coordinate[label=right:F] (F) -- (B)
(F) -- ++(-8,0,0) coordinate[label=left:E] (E) -- (A) (E) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (A) -- ++(0,5,0) coordinate[label=left:D] (D) -- (E)
(D) -- (C) (D) -- (B);
\draw[red] (A) ++ ($\CornerScale*(1,0,0)$) --++ ($\CornerScale*(0,0.75,0.3)$) 
-- ++($\CornerScale*(-1,0,0)$)
(C) ++ ($\CornerScale*(0,-0.75,0)$) --++ ($\CornerScale*(0,0,0.6)$) -- 
++ ($\CornerScale*(0,0.75,0)$)
(F) ++ ($\CornerScale*(0,-0.75,-0.3)$) --++ ($\CornerScale*(-1,0,0)$) -- 
++($\CornerScale*(0,0.75,0.3)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I edit the size of the right angle? Thank you.

Comment: @Alsacelei I added a parameter `\CornerScale` which with you can play.